Looking for a fantasy manga, isekai or otherwise, where the MC can pull swords out from his dimensional space, typically a wooden and metal sword
I can only vaguely remember this manga, but I think its pretty recent. The distinct trait of this manga is the MC can pull swords out from his dimensional space, one being a wooden practice sword that has a little branch with a leaf on it, and the other one being a metal sword that may have some kinda of demonic power on it. The MC may or may not be able to craft things. Its a long shot but I hope you guys can help.

Maybe one of the works listed here (warning, TVTropes link): https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Hammerspace/AnimeAndManga

There are barely any details, but this reminds me strongly of
Reincarnated as the Mastermind of the Story
NovelUpdates link, I could only find fan scanlations.

protagonist can summon sword
skill is called demonic sword summon
initially he summons wooden sword, later he learns to summon metal one

